# Logic of the presentation component Angular?

Tags: angular

There is a custom component `app-badge`, that created colored badges and custom text:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-badge',
    templateUrl: './badge.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./badge.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class BadgeComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() badge: Badge;
    @Input() cssClass: string;
    @Output() onSelect = new EventEmitter<Badge>();
    public isSelected: boolean;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {}

    public select() {
        this.onSelect.emit(this.badge);
        this.isSelected = !this.isSelected;
    }
}
```

**Template is:**

```
<span (click)="select()" class="badge p-2 mb-1 mr-2" [ngClass]="{ 'primary-color-dark': isSelected, 'badge-unchecked': !isSelected }">{{
    badge.label
}}</span>
```

I use this component inside another `<app-sidebar>`:

```
<app-badge
    *ngFor="let pagesize of paginationService.getPageSizeOptions()"
    [badge]="{ label: pagesize, value: pagesize }"
    [cssClass]="'primary'"
    (onSelect)="setPageSize($event)"
></app-badge>
```

Seems it is not bad, but I faced with problem, where to write two logic cases:

1. Set only one badge active
2. Set any badge as active

So, I dont want a logic of setting badges in parent component `<app-sidebar>`. I want to incapsultate this inside itdelf.

I not confident, may be my component structure is wrong, therefore I have issues.

Comment: I think it should be additionally `app-badge-list component` that should have logic of setting/selecting badges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there are multiple app-badge instances and you want specific states. Then it's a good idea to put a variable to contain that state like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-badge',
    templateUrl: './badge.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./badge.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class BadgeComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() badge: Badge;
    @Input() cssClass: string;
    @Output() onSelect = new EventEmitter<Badge>();
    public isSelected: boolean;
    active:false;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {}
    public onSetActiveProperty(value){
       this.active=value;
       // now do something with the newly set value
    }
    public select() {
        this.onSelect.emit(this.badge);
        this.isSelected = !this.isSelected;
    }
}
```

This gives a property to set the value, and if desired do something about it, like change a class etc.

Comment: What if I need to disable to set all badges, only one? Where this logic should be places? Now BadgeComponent is like just presentation component.

Comment: Two ways, use an array.map and set to the value you want, or event better, send an event. In that case all badges are listening for that event and do what you want.